# Is ternary operator, if-else or logical OR faster in javascript?

Tags: javascript, performance

Which method is faster or more responsive in javascript, if-else, the ternary operator or logical OR? Which is advisable to use, for what reasons?

Comment: This is beyond micro-optimazation.  This is like nano-optimization.  Would you really change your coding style to save 0.0000000000001ms?!

Comment: If the perf difference between these really matters to you, Javascript is probably not the right language to be using.

Comment: Why did I get so annoyed because of the answers to this question? idk...

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The speed difference will be negligible - use whichever you find to be more readable.  In other words I highly doubt that a bottleneck in your code will be due to using the wrong conditional construct.

Comment: It's supposed to be negligible. But we need tests to make sure some browser like IE didn't screw it up.

Comment: Speed is important when handling millions of data in JavaScript

Comment: While I agree with this, the question is asking which method is faster. Aka this answer doesn't really answer the question. - I was actually curious to know for a similar reason that @Kira brought up

Comment: html5 game devs would benefit from knowing as well, We use if statements alot, so it's quite safe to say every millisecond counts  sadly.

Answer (score 144):

Seems like nobody did any actual profiling. Here's the code I used:

```js
test = function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < 10000000; i++) {
        var a = i < 100 ? 1 : 2;

        /*
        if(i < 100) {
            var a = 1;
        }else{
            var a = 2;
        }
        */
    }
}

test();
```

Using the `if`/`else` block instead of the ternary operator yields a **1.5** - **2x** performance increase in *Google Chrome v21* under *OS X Snow Leopard*.

As one use case where this is **very** important, synthesizing real-time audio is becoming more and more common with JavaScript. This type of performance difference is a big deal when an algorithm is running 44100 times a second.

Comment: just found this site / test today: http://jsperf.com/ternary-vs-switch which confirms my findings. However, when I ran the tests in Safari using the ternary operator was slightly faster... wouldn't want to make things simple for us :)

Comment: In 32Bit Firefox 27 on Windows 8.1 64Bit Ternary is fastest for me, Switch slowest, if-else halfway inbetween.

Comment: Thank you. I hate when all these people say "over optimizing" when there legit reasons for almost any optimization question.

Comment: Do you mean performance improvement (faster) or time increase (slower)?

Comment: faster. at least around three years ago... I would run the linked jsperf test yourself as such results are certainly subject to change.

Answer (score 41):

I didn't think @charlie robert's test was fair

## Here's my [jsperf](http://jsperf.com/ternary-vs-simple-if-else)

result:

1. strict equal is the fastest
2. strict ternary is 33% slower
3. truthy falsy is 49% slower
4. ternary truthy falsy is 55% slower
5. if else and ternary are roughly the same.

normal equal and normal ternary slowest.

### strict equals:

```
var a = true, b;

if (a === true) {
  b = true;
} else {
  b = false
}
if (a === false) {
  b = true;
} else {
  b = false;
}
```

### ternary strict equals

```
var a = true, b;

b = (a === true) ? true : false;

b = (a === false) ? true : false;
```

### simple equality

```
 var a = true, b;

    if (a == true) {
      b = true;
    } else {
      b = false;
    }

    if (a == false) {
      b = true;
    } else {
      b = false;
    }
```

### simple ternary equality

```
 var a = true, b;
    b = (a == true) ? true : false;

    b = (a == false) ? true : false;
```

### truthy / falsy

```
var a = true, b;
if (a) {
  b = true;
} else {
  b = false;
}

if (!a) {
  b = true;
} else {
  b = false;
}
```

### ternary truthy / falsy

```
var a = true, b;
b = (a) ? true : false;
b = (!a) ? true : false;
```

Answer (score 3):

to charlie roberts' answer above, I would add:

the following link gives some incisive answers; the result for switches in Firefox being the most striking:
http://jsperf.com/if-else-vs-arrays-vs-switch-vs-ternary/39

Those who question why anyone would investigate optimization to this degree would do well to research WebGL!

Answer (score 1):

Ternary operator is only syntactic sugar, not a performance booster.

Comment: According to benchmarks it is - https://jsperf.com/ternary-vs-simple-if-else

Answer (score 0):

I think this will helps to find exact speed difference of the if..else and ternary operator. I checked different types of nested conditions for both ternary and if else. it shows ternary is more faster than if..else statement(Nodejs console, Chrome and Edge)  but in the case of Firefox, shows opposite result (Windows 10). The below code gives the 40 average milliseconds for both test.

```
const IfTest = () => {
  let sum = 0;
  for (let x = 0; x < 1e8; ++x) {
    if (x % 2 === 0) 
     sum += x;
    else if (x > 1e8 / 2) 
     sum += 5;
    else 
     sum += 6;
  }
};

const TernaryTest = () => {
  let sum = 0;
  for (let x = 0; x < 1e8; ++x) {
    sum += x % 2 === 0 ? x : x > 1e8 / 2 ? 5 : 6;
  }
};

const initTest = (e) => {
  let [tAverage, ifAverage] = [0, 0];
  for (let x = 0; x < e; ++x) {
    const date = new Date;
    IfTest();
    ifAverage += new Date - date;
  }
  console.log("if execution time:", ifAverage / e);

  for (let x = 0; x < e; ++x) {
    const date = new Date;
    TernaryTest();
    tAverage += new Date - date;
  }
  console.log("ternary execution time:", tAverage / e);
};

initTest(40);
```

Answer (score -2):

I'm doing another syntax:

```
var a = true,
    b;

b = (a == false) 
    ? true // if a == false, b = true
    : false; // else: a == true so b = false

    /* Equivalent of
    if(a == true)
      var b = true;
    else
      var b = false;
```

Some people like my code and tell me it's simple to read.

Comment: this can be simplified to `b = !a`

Comment: so many smells:
use `let` not `var`;
don't declare values without value;
use strict equal;
don't comment obvious stuff;
`let a = true; let b = !a;`

Answer (score -3):

There is no difference in speed.

Some prefer the if/else for readability. Personally, I use the ternary operator whenever the logic is trivial enough to understand on one line.