# Need help to understand a c# statement

Tags: c#

Hi need a little help understanding the following statement and the logic of what its doing.

```
AuthenticationProvider auth = 
    (level & Levels.Authentication) == Levels.Authentication
        ? GetAuthenticationProviderByName(authentication, authPhrase)
        : DefaultAuthenticationProvider.Instance;
```

I see im making an AuthentcationProvider, but then I dont understand  whats happening why is there a comparison there and whats is the question mark doing?

Thanks.

Comment: This is what the question mark is doing: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3312786/benefits-of-using-the-conditional-ternary-operator

Comment: Google is your friend, you know.

Comment: @Baboon did you ever try googling for `?` and `:`?

Comment: @Baboon google is alright if you know what your looking for, I couldn't tell what it was logically doing and mark byers answer puts it in a logically clear manor. Thanks for your two cents

Comment: It's called a question mark, third result on google when you type "C# question mark".

Comment: @Baboon how would you use your excellent google craft to extract the logical path of the statement.

Comment: I wouldn't qualify 3 words in google and a button pressed as "excellent". Which is why i downvoted. Now the matter is closed, you got your answer, next time give it an honest try before asking a question. Happy coding.

Comment: @Baboon yet again you decided not to answer the question but make a smart ass remark

Comment: When you downvote, SO recommands to comment to explain why. I'm explaining. What's the problem now? You're a ball of anger man...

Comment: @Baboon <calm-voice>I'm not angry, You down voted because you though that I could google the answer to this, and I'm challenging that. If you can show me how to google for this you win.</calm-voice>

Comment: Like i said, the third result on google when you type "C# question mark" answers your question. (google adapts the result for the user, so you will probably find another site/blog than me, but you will find a result).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `?` and `:` here is called the [conditional operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx) (it is also sometimes known as the ternary operator).

The code you posted is equivalent to this:

```
AuthenticationProvider auth;
if ((level & Levels.Authentication) == Levels.Authentication) { 
    auth = GetAuthenticationProviderByName(authentication, authPhrase);
} else {
    auth = DefaultAuthenticationProvider.Instance;
}
```

The `&` is a "bitwise and". Here it used here to test to see if the `Levels.Authentication` bit is set.

Answer (score 1):

It's the [Ternary operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx):

```
condition ? first_expression : second_expression;
```

So like a short version of `if...else`.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it's doing a bit-wise compare between level and Levels.Authentication.  I'm assuming level is a "flags" variable, and it's checking if the Levels.Authentication flag is on.

If so it does the GetAuthenticationByName, if not it does the DefaultAuthenticationProvider.Instance.

Answer (score 1):

`level` is a variable of type Levels, which is an `enum` decorated with the `FlagsAttribute`.

This means that you can combine multiple values of that enum in one variable.

The line `level & LevelsAuthentication == Levels.Authentication`, checks if the level variable has the value `Levels.Authentication` set.

If this is true, the `GetAuthenticationProviderByName(authentication, authPrase)` statement is executed.
if it is false, the D`efaultAuthenticationProvider.Instance` is returned.

For more information check out:

- [FlagsAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.flagsattribute.aspx)
- [Bitwise operators](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6a71f45d%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)
- [Ternary operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

?:

is the conditional operator, see here: [?: Operator (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

it works like this:

```
s = x != 0.0 ? Math.Sin(x)/x : 1.0;
```

assigning to s `Math.Sin(x)/x` only if `x != 0`