# C# - Are there any advantages or benefits to using ternary operators?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Are there any advantages or benefits to using tertiary operators for if statements?

For example, is the following more efficient? Or considered better programming practice?

```
variable1 = string.IsNullOrEmpty(variable2) ? "string value" : "";
```

Compared to the following format:

```
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(variable2))
        {
            variable1 = "string value"
        } else
        {
            variable1 = "";
        }
```

Comment: It's "ternary operator".

Comment: Actually it's the 'conditional operator'. Ternary merely indicates that the operator has 3 parts

Comment: Please read the [faq#close] - "*this question will likely solicit opinion, debate, arguments, polling, or extended discussion.*"

Comment: @rich.okelly actually, it's "conditional operator" (see the C# specification section 7.14).  "Ternary" describes the operator, but is not part of its name.  Because it is *the only* ternary operator, however, people can call it "the ternary operator" without ambiguity.

Comment: It's entirely a question of readability, which is, of course, nearly entirely subjective.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Benefits of using the conditional ?: (ternary) operator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3312786/benefits-of-using-the-conditional-ternary-operator)

Comment: @jadarnel27 This is a reasonable question.  Programmers need to know how to make decisions between different approaches to solving a given problem.  However, the question is a duplicate, so I have voted to close it for that reason.

Comment: @phoog I agree that it's a reasonable question.  It's just not on-topic *for Stack Overflow*.  It's not within the scope outlined in the faq.  Just my opinion though, I'm sure some would disagree.

Comment: phoog is correct; this is a perfectly reasonable question because there are both technical and human factor differences that motivate this programming decision. But it is a duplicate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ternary operator is more concise: less typing and quicker to read.  The compiled IL code or the JITted native code are likely to be identical.  If not, any performance differences are almost certain to be virtually unmeasurably small.  Therefore, source code quality is the only real consideration in making the decision.

"Tertiary" means "third in importance"; "ternary" means "having three parts."

I personally prefer the term "conditional operator" because it's entirely possible that someone will invent another ternary operator in the future.  Imagine if we had to call `+` the "first binary operator" and `-` the "second binary operator"!

Answer (score 8):

For a situation like this, the conditional ternary operator is better. The code is vastly more readable and maintainable for experienced programmers. There is no meaningful difference in performance, period.

Comment: No meaningful difference?  Unless I'm mistaken, the two compile to exactly the same bytecode.  I'm pretty sure the conditional operator is just shorthand for the `if` block...

Comment: `?:` has identical semantics to a certain `if` statement, but AFAIK, the specification does not say that `?:` is **shorthand** for that equivalent `if` statement.

Answer (score 2):

It is required on databinding expressions

```
<asp:Label runat="server" 
        Text='<%# (bool)Eval("Active") ? "Active" : "Disabled"' />
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no difference other than preference.  As far as actually being more readable, that is a matter of religion as one group of programmers will say 'yes', and the other 'no'.  One advantage that the expanded (if/then/else) form has is that it is easier to add additional statements to the braches.  Also, if you need to nest additional conditional logic, if/then/else would be the preferred method.

Answer (score 1):

There is no performance gain, but it is generally thought to be better.  It uses less to describe the same set of operations as your other example.

Answer (score 1):

If you ever want to execute more than one statement in the blocks you will need to refactor the code, but its an easy refactoring.  Some may argue that it reduces code readability.  As far as pure functionality there is no difference.