# C# Statement (Select?)

Tags: c#, syntax

I forgot the syntax of a C# statement and I don't even know the name....

lets say you have a boolean, call it connected, and i want to set some text depending on the connected status. i know there is a simple "one liner" statement but i forgot the syntax and i don't know the name of the type of statement so i can google search it.

here is something close to what i am looking for. the syntax looks something like the following:

```
string title = ( connected : "[Not Connected]", "[Connected]");
```

thanks!

Comment: Search ternary operator in C#. It is the only operator in OOPS working on 3 operands.

Comment: [Benefits of using this operator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3312786/benefits-of-using-the-conditional-ternary-operator)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are looking for the [conditional operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28%28v=vs.100%29.aspx):

```
string title = connected ? "[Connected]" : "[Not Connected]";
```

Comment: This is a very nice "compact" statement. I love it when I get a chance to use it. :)

Answer (score 5):

It's called a [Conditional/ternary operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

```
string title = connected ? "[Not Connected]": "[Connected]";
```

**Note** The true condition comes first so in your example it should actually be

```
string title = connected ? "[Connected]": "[Not Connected]";
```

Comment: conditional operator or ternary operator?

Comment: @TackyTacky Ternary simply means "3 operands", it's a conditional operator.

Comment: Both. The conditional operator is a ternary operator as it takes three operands.

Comment: It's the only operator with three operands, so ternary operator uniquely identifies the operator, but conditional operator describes what it does. Both names are valid.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth Was just editting that, had used it from the question example

Comment: @hvd: It's *currently* the only ternary operator, but that's still a bad reason to use it as a name. That's like calling `protected` "the nine letter access modifier"...

Comment: @JonSkeet I do call it the conditional operator, but I don't object if others don't.

Comment: @Manatherin: You said `"[Connected]"` should come first when your first statement can be rewritten as `string title = !connected ? "[Not Connected]": "[Connected]";`

Comment: @hvd: It's like arguments vs parameters, and what "pass by reference" means - I think it's worth trying to keep everyone consistent, for clarity. I'm like that though ;)

Comment: No objection to that from me :)

Comment: @NikhilAgrawal point taken, i was merely trying pointing out that the condition for the true should come first (and keeping it consistent with OP's example)

Answer (score 5):

I think you mean the [*conditional operator*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx):

```
// Sample changed from original code for sanity
string title = connected ? "[Connected]" : "[Not connected]";
```

Its proper name is the conditional operator, but you'll sometimes here people referring to it as "the ternary operator". That *just* means it has three operands (vs the unary operators and binary operators) - it doesn't describe what it *does* at all, and IMO should be avoided. Use its proper name, which describes what it's for: evaluating a *condition* and then evaluating another expression based on that.

See section 7.14 of the C# 4 spec for details on behaviour etc.

Comment: `connected ? "[Not connected]" ...`? Are you sure?

Comment: @Serge: I was just going by the code in the question. Edited.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you're talking about the ternary-[conditional operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28).

```
string title = condition ? "on true" : "on false";
```

Note this is not the "ternary operator" as many people might think, ternary simply means to have 3 operands, you can [read more on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_operation).

> In computer science, a ternary operator (sometimes incorrectly called a tertiary operator) is an operator that takes three arguments

Comment: Under the covers is the compiler really creating code that takes three arguments or does it convert the statement to it's equivalent:   if (connected) text = "connected" else text = "not connected"; It seems as if the conditional operator is just a syntactical convenience and doesn't really represent the underlying code.

Comment: @TackyTacky The best way would be to look for yourself, compile a simple application and take a look in the ILDASM to see how it's constructed. Also read 14.13 of the C# Language Spec for more information on the operator. But yes, you're right, this is a convenience operator.

Answer (score 0):

Enter the [conditional operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28%28VS.80%29.aspx)

```
var title = connected ?  "Connected" : "Not Connected"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
title= (connected == true) ? "[Connected]" : "[Not Connected]";
```

or

```
title= (connected) ? "[Connected]" : "[Not Connected]";
```

Comment: It can be reduced to `title = connected ? "[Connected]" : "[Not Connected]";`