# Java on JCreator (creating a LEAP YEAR program using while loop)

Tags: java, while-loop, multiple-conditions

```
public class LeapYear_2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    int year = 1900;                
        while (year <= 2100 && (year % 4 == 0)){

            System.out.println(year + " Is a Leap Year");
            year++;

            System.out.println(year + " Is not a leap year");
            year++;
        }   

    }
}
```

I just want to know if whats wrong with my Codes? I want to create a program that year 1900 to 2100 will show the leap year and which is NOT.

I just dont know how to use while with many conditions... it seems that I have to have many conditions in while loop in order for this program to work as i want to.

Comment: I'd like to add that in most presented answers, 1900 will show up as a leap year. That is because there's only a check to see if the year is divisible by 4, but a centurial year should also be divisible by 400. Therefore, 1900 is not a leap year but 2000 is.

Comment: @kmae Yes you're right, I edited my answer to take this into account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### This is what you want to do :

public class TestLeapYear {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int year = 1900;                
    while (year <= 2100 ){

        if (year % 4 == 0){
            System.out.println(year + " Is a Leap Year");
            year++;
        }
        else {
            System.out.println(year + " Is not a leap year");
            year++;
        }
    }   

}


}
```

This code goes through all years from 1900 to 2100 and for each of them checks if it is a leap year (year%4==0). Then it prints accordingly.

**Edit** : you can also do it in one line using the [ternary operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3312786/benefits-of-using-the-conditional-ternary-operator) (condition ? doIfTrue: doIfFalse) (but it is less readable...)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int year = 1900;                
    while (year <= 2100 ){
            System.out.println(year + " Is "+ ((year % 4 == 0)? "" : "not")+" a Leap Year");
            year++;

    }   

}
```

### In your original Code :

You are misusing the while loop. The principle of a while loop is to do the same thing until a condition is true.

So this :

```
 while(condition){ doSomething()}
```

can be translated into : while the condition is true then I'll doSomething() when it's not true anymore I'll continue.

In your original code the condition is `year <= 2100 && (year % 4 == 0)` so it is true only if the year is lesser or equal to 2100 **AND** the year modulo 4 equals 0. And this is this second condition that is false thus exiting the loop.

See how I used an IF ELSE statement inside the loop ? The loop is going through all the years and for each of them we test if it is a leap year of not.

### About Leap Years :

Your way of determining if a year is a leap year is not complete. [Wikipedia proposes a good algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_year#Algorithm) :

```
 if year is divisible by 400 then
   is_leap_year
 else if year is divisible by 100 then
   not_leap_year
 else if year is divisible by 4 then
   is_leap_year
 else
   not_leap_year
```

Comment: Thanks this is EXACTLY what I want to do.... now I know that I can put if else statement into a while loop... Thank you very much!

Comment: another question sir! is there any way I can group the Leap year and the not leap year..

Comment: yes you can, see my edit. Not the best way to go for a beginner but that's good to know it exists and what it does

Comment: @JoeyEguna You can also put a while into and if into a while that's into an if. In fact you can go as deep as you want. Consider upvoting, accepting answers that were usefull to you.

Comment: how to do this sir? (condition ? doIfTrue: doIfFalse) and what do you mean about less readable?

Comment: Sorry the link I put was broken. Consider looking into the pros and cons of this solution. This page is a good start : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3312786/benefits-of-using-the-conditional-ternary-operator But there are many more !

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you are looking for:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
int year = 1900;                
    while (year <= 2100){
        if (year % 4 == 0) {
            System.out.println(year + " Is a Leap Year");
            year++;
        }
        else {
            System.out.println(year + " Is not a leap year");
            year++;
        }
    }
}
```

So the while loop takes care of looping through all the years and the if statement checks each year if it matches your leap year query. When you have that in your while loop as you did, whenever you run across a non-leap year it will also break the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Just for fun a cheat code ;)

```
int count = 0;
for (int i = 1900; i < 2100; i++){
 if (count == 4){
  System.out.println(i + " Is a Leap Year");
  count = 0;
  }
  count++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this single condition will work as you want
here I used ternary operator ,it works same as if else condition ,
Basic syntax is `your condition ? true : false`

```
in your case 
    condition : year % 4==0 
    true :  year Is a Leap Year
    false : year Is a not Leap Year


            int year = 1900;                
            while (year <= 2100){
                System.out.println(year % 4==0 ? year+" Is a Leap Year" :year + " Is not a leap year" );
                year++;
            }
```

Comment: You should also explain _what_ is a ternary operator and _what_ it does, it's not so easy for beginners.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to add that in most presented answers, 1900 will show up as a leap year. That is because there's only a check to see if the year is divisible by 4, but a centurial year should also be divisible by 400. Therefore, 1900 is not a leap year but 2000 is.

The condition should actually be

```
if(year % 4 == 0 && !(year % 100 == 0 && year % 400 != 0))
  // now we have a leap year.
```

furthermore, while I'm at it, you could do the following as well

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();   
cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);   
if(cal.getActualMaximum(DAY_OF_YEAR) > 365)
  // leap year.
```

but that would be rather expensive to repeat 200 times, in comparison to the modulo-operations.