# javascript question mark ?: logical syntax, defensive programming

Tags: javascript, function, variables, if-statement, defensive-programming

I am trying to re-write the statement below using the javascript ?: syntax.

```
if(type of someVariable !="undefined"){
     someFunction(someVariable);
}else{}
```

This is my current attempt and it's causing a syntax error

```
typeof someVariable != "undefined" ? someFunction(someVariable) : ;
```

If any one can tell met what I'm doing wrong I'd appreciate it. Any accompanying tips on best practices for defensive programing are welcome.

Answer (score 5):

?: style (requires expressions on either side of the `:`):

```
typeof(someVariable) != 'undefined' ? someFunction : null;
```

Ninja-style:

```
someVariable !== undefined && someFunction(someVariable);
```

[Edit: I couldn've sworn `noop` was a thing in Javascript, but apparently I was wrong.  Switched to `null`]

Comment: `jQuery.noop` is a thing

Answer (score 0):

It should look like this.

```
someVariable != undefined ? someFunction(someVariable):someOtherfunction(someOtherVarialbe);
```

if you do not want else statement and want it in single line you can do like this:

```
  if(someVariable != undefined){someFunction(someVariable);}
```

Comment: `typeof` isn't a function. You don't need the `()` after it. And it returns a string, so you need to compare to `"undefined"`. But better to just do `someVariable != undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

even though the ternary operation controls the program flow, I'd use it only in assignment operation or when returning a value from a function.

check this out:
[Benefits of using the conditional ?: (ternary) operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3312786/benefits-of-using-the-conditional-ternary-operator)