# Can I replace an if / else with two levels of ? :

Tags: c#

I have the following C# code:

```
        if (client.Action == "show")
        {
            result = "s";
        }
        else
        {
            result = answersCorrect ? "t" : "f";
        }
```

Is there a way I can remove the if and else and use two levels of ? and :

Comment: Yea, you can. Try it.

Comment: Check this<http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3312786/benefits-of-using-the-conditional-ternary-operator> before you going to use.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sure, you can:

```
var result = client.Action == "show" ? "s" : (answersCorrect ? "t" : "f");
```

A good question to ask yourself, though, is whether this approach is more readable.

Answer (score 2):

use

```
var result = client.Action == "show" ? "s" : (answersCorrect ? "t" : "f");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 result = client.Action == "show" ?  "s" : answersCorrect ? "t" : "f"
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
result=(client.Action == "show")?"s":((answersCorrect) ? "t" : "f");
```