# What does this line syntax heavy line of code mean?

Tags: c#, string, syntax, ternary-operator

I am working on a project where I found a syntax heavy line of code in it

```
logonuser = logonuser.IndexOf(domain) >= 0 ? logonuser : domain + "\\" + logonuser;
```

Both logonuser and domain are Strings.
I need an explanation of what it is and how does it work?

Comment: It's assigning a value of `logonuser` to itself if the domain is found in the string, otherwise it is prepending the domain and assigning it to `logonuser`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Benefits of using the conditional ?: (ternary) operator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3312786/benefits-of-using-the-conditional-ternary-operator)

Answer (score 3):

this is the [ternary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx) operator

it's like saying:

```
if(logonuser.IndexOf(domain) >= 0)
{
     logonuser = logonuser;
}
else
{
     logonuser = domain + "\\" + logonuser;
}
```

Comment: Although if you wrote it in verbose format, you would only write the else case :)

Answer (score 0):

As others already stated, that's the ternary operator. The explanation of the code besides the fact that is using this operator is:

- If longuser is a "absolute"(*) url containing the domain, then use it without changing it.
- else (longuser is a relative url) build a absolute url using the domain

(*) Not really absolute without the protocol