# c programming: Conversion of < ? : type condition to simple if else

Tags: c

Can somebody tell me what does the following expression mean in a C code?

```
A = B < C ? B:C;
```

I know that it's an if-else condition, but don't know it works. I will appreciate if somebody wrote it in simple if else conditions.

Don't have reputation to comment/feedback or appreciate.

Comment: @DavidL: you mark it with a duplicate in C, not C#?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem, look at question tags. For `C#` the closest duplicate probably is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3312786/1997232).

Answer (score 1):

You can translate it to the following:

```
if (B < C)
    A = B;
else
    A = C;
```

This is called a [ternary operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator) (or in C# conditional operator).

It returns the value after the question mark if the condition is true and otherwise returns the value after the colon:

```
condition ? ReturnedIfConditionIsTrue : ReturnedIfConditionIsFalse
```