# Read condition of a loop while C#

Tags: c#, while-loop, conditional-statements

I can't read the condition in the while ... it should start with: until the i is equal to..., and then I don't understand.

```
    private int[] array1;
    private int[] array2;
    private int index;
    private bool scale;

    for (int i = 0; i <= 100; i++)
    {
        while (i == (scale ? array1[index] : array1[index]))
        {

        }
    }
```

How should I read the while condition completely?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Benefits of using the conditional ?: (ternary) operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3312786/benefits-of-using-the-conditional-ternary-operator)

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator

Comment: This doesn't make sense `scale ? array1[index] : array1[index]`, you get the same `array1[index]` value when `scale` is `true` or `false`. Your question is very unclear, what do you wan't to achieve using this code

Comment: maybe you'll need to update your ternary operator to `scale ? array1[index] : array2[index]`

Comment: Ahd it's still a constant. If the while-loop is not filled with code, it's very likely endless, so the program would freeze.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

? mean is true or false.

scale is true -> send array1[index]

scale is false -> send array2[index]