# are javascript shorthand ifs faster?

Tags: javascript, optimization

In an angularJs app, I'm checking if a variable is undefined, make the call to window.innerHeight happen only once.
I have been told that changing this:

```
        if(typeof inner_height === 'undefined'){
            inner_height = window.innerHeight;               
            console.log('innesr_height was undefined, now '+inner_height);
            }    
        var h_val = calcPixels(inner_height, valueInPersent) 
        console.log('h_val is '+h_val);
        return h_val;
```

to this:

```
        return (h_val)?h_hval:h_hval = window.innerHeight;
```

is the shorthand syntax considerably faster?

Comment: short circuiting is faster then nesting if statements, but the shorthand is still compiled and run the same way as if statements i believe

Comment: Maybe have a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2586842/javascript-if-else-or-ternary-operator-is-faster and a jsperf: http://jsperf.com/ternary-operator-vs-if-statement/2

Comment: From what I can see, the codes do entirely different things, so I'm not sure why you would want to compare their performance.

Comment: I would use shorthand for easier syntax, not really for performance. If it's any different it won't be by much.