# json null property after creating new property

Tags: javascript

```
jsonArr = [
    {
        "val": "0"
    },
    {
        "val": "1"
    },
    {
        "val": "2"
    },
    {
        "val": "2"
    },
    {
        "val": "2"
    },
    {
        "val": "0"
    },
    {
        "val": "0"
    },
    {
        "val": "4"
    }
    ];
var val = {};
for (var i = 0; i < jsonArr.length; i++) {
    if (val.hasOwnProperty(jsonArr[i].val)) { // if the property exists
        val[jsonArr[i].val] = 1; // create new property
    } else {
        val[jsonArr[i].val] ++; // increase
    }
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(val));
```

`Console.log` is spitting out `{"0":1,"1":null,"2":1,"4":null}`, I don't see where the null is coming from as I declare it `= 1`? Also you can see it's not increasing as it should otherwise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set property to `1` if `jsonArr[i].val` does *not* exist:

```
var val = {};
for (var i = 0; i < jsonArr.length; i++) {
    if (!val.hasOwnProperty(jsonArr[i].val)) {
        val[jsonArr[i].val] = 1;
    } else {
        val[jsonArr[i].val]++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh. My. God. What a *derp* moment.

Comment: :) sometimes you just need a fresh eye.

Answer (score 2):

You've not set the value for `val[jsonArr[i].val] ++;`
 Instead you're trying to increment it.

At first when the value doesn't exist, you must set it to 1.

```
for (var i = 0; i < jsonArr.length; i++) {
    val[jsonArr[i].val] = val[jsonArr[i].val] ? val[jsonArr[i].val]++ : 1; 
}
```

I've used a ternary operator which checks for the value of the property in `val` object. If it doesn't exist it sets it to 1 else increments its value.

If you're considering performance:

```
for (var i = 0; i < jsonArr.length; i++) {
        var value = jsonArr[i].val; // this will avoid some lookup
        val[value] = val[value] ? val[value]++ : 1; 
}
```

Comment: Interesting approach, is there any advantages to this method over the one I chose? Performance wise?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2586842/javascript-if-else-or-ternary-operator-is-faster I guess not, but interesting enough!

Comment: yes, its very negligible. But one thign you can do, since you are referring `jsonArr[i].val` in multiple locations, you can store it in some variable. It will help in performance

Comment: Speak of the devil, did that right before you said it!