# chosse between conditional operator and function call inside template

Tags: angularjs, angular-template

My question is about choosing which of these two approach is better and faster.

I have below template which applies any one out of three classes based on conditions.

**Approach 1:**

I use a ternary operator inside template

```
data-ng-class="(data.selectionStatus[id] === 'RED') ? 'red-class' : (data.selectionStatus[id] === 'BLUE') ? 'blue-class' : 'no-color-class'"
```

**Approach 2:**

Instead of using conditions in template, use a function which will return the correct value.

```
Template:
           data-ng-class="getSelectionStatus(id)"


JavaScript:

           $scope.getSelectionStatus = function (id) {

                /*get status using id*/
                var selectionStatus =  $rootScope.data.selectionStatus[id];

                if (selectionStatus === 'RED') {
                    return 'red-class';
                } else if (selectionStatus === 'BLUE') {
                    return 'blue-class'';
                } else {
                    return 'no-color-class';
                }
            };
```

P.S. I use AngularJS v1.3.10.

Comment: use object syntax, easier to read

Comment: @charlietfl,  Sorry I didn't understand you.

Comment: like: `ng-class="{'red-class': data.selectionStatus[id] == 'RED','blue-class': data.selectionStatus[id] == 'BLUE', 'no-color-class': !data.selectionStatus[id]}"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you haven't read John Papa's Angular style guide (https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md), I highly recommend it. It doesn't have a specific rule for you situation, but the principles and rules explained in it will help you make the best decision for your project.

As far as speed goes, technically one approach ***IS*** faster than the other. However, it can vary from browser to browser:
[javascript if/else or ternary operator is faster?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2586842/javascript-if-else-or-ternary-operator-is-faster)

So, unless you are dealing with real-time audio in javascript, readability far out-weighs the negligible performance difference of these two approaches. Approach #2 is much more readable in my opinion than the first approach. That's not to say that some situations force you to use Approach #1.

If you are precompiling your templates into javascript, you could get away with placing your logic on new lines like this:

```
<div data-ng-class="(data.selectionStatus[id] === 'RED') ?
    'red-class' : 
    (data.selectionStatus[id] === 'BLUE') ?
        'blue-class' : 
        'no-color-class'">
```

But it's not recommend. Even on separate lines, it's not very readable. As charlietfl mentioned, using object syntax also improves readability, slightly. Even more so if you place it on multiple lines:

```
<div data-ng-class="{
    'red-class': data.selectionStatus[id] === 'RED', 
    'blue-class': data.selectionStatus[id] === 'BLUE',
    'no-color-class': !data.selectionStatus[id] 
}">
```

If you really want to get wild 'n crazy, you could use a switch statement. There's no performance difference, but it's much more readable than either solution:

```
       $scope.getSelectionStatus = function (id) {

            /*get status using id*/
            var selectionStatus =  $rootScope.data.selectionStatus[id];

            switch (selectionStatus) {
              case 'RED':
                return 'red-class';
                break;
              case: 'BLUE':
                return 'blue-class';
                break;
              default:
                return 'no-color-class';
            }
        };
```