# Unable to use ternary operator within object data

Tags: javascript

I am using JavaScript and jQuery for my web application. In one case I have used the ternary operator in order to optimize  the code while assigning object values.

I have manually set the `d` value to true for testing. But this value will vary based on customer given data in my application.

```
d=true;
var args = { d ? { target:"div"} : {main:"body"}, status:"enabled", updated:"yes" };
```

But this does not work and throws script error. Can you suggest how to update object data in optimized way.

Comment: There is a `)` after "body" that shouldn't be there

Comment: i have removed that. its inserted wronly while updating query here

Comment: you are inserting an object where a key: value is expected, you need a key for the object you are inserting

Comment: I need something like this in args : Object {target: "div", status: "enabled", updated: "yes", type: "click", model: Object…}

Comment: What do you mean by optimized way ? readability ? performances ? number of lines  ?

Comment: number of lines like maxx did in answers section

Comment: My 2 cents : reducing number of lines won't always make your program run faster and/or increase maintainability. Also ternary operators are not as fast as strict comparison : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2586842/javascript-if-else-or-ternary-operator-is-faster . Ask yourself what does really matter ;)

Comment: yeah ok thanks for your suggsetion. Since we are using more no of conditions and data, i am came here to find to reduce the number of lines.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Thats incorrect JavaScript syntax, You cant dynamicaly define properies on object this way. You can do this:

```
var args = {status:"enabled", updated:"yes"};
d ? (args.target = "div") : (args.main = "body");
```

In ES2015 you can do:

```
var args = {[d ? "target" : "main"]: d ? "div" : "body", status:"enabled", updated:"yes"};
```

Comment: already i having this option only. But now i have to optimize the code since i have more no of args like this. So only i am searching for this

Comment: Your second option is awesome. this is what i am expecting thank u

Answer (score 4):

You cannot use this operator in an object this way. Moreover, the data structure is incorrect. It would result in the following object :

```
{ { target:"whatever"} , status:"enabled", updated:"yes" };
```

Which is syntactically incorrect.

Consider writing something like this :

```
var args = {status:"enabled", updated:"yes" };
if(d){
    args.target = 'div';
} else {
    args.main = 'body';
}
```