# Angular template ternary or method

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I had a basic simple question I was looking on the net not really found an answer.I was making a reactive form with a number only field so I did:

```
<input type="number" formControlName="view" />
```

Now I had my number field only I could write , and .
So my two solutions are:

Ternary:

`(keydown)="$event.keyCode !== 188 ? $event.keyCode !== 190: $event.preventDefault()"`

Or method:

```
private keypress(_event: any) {
    if (_event.keyCode === 188 || _event.keyCode === 190)
    {
        _event.preventDefault();
    }
}
```

Between these are there any performance I should know of?
Related to this question: is calling a component method taking more time then doing ternary?

Comment: input tag with type number will automatically allow only numbers and dot. it will not allow comma. what you want to do with the input field? As far as I know both ternary and if conditions are same. method will be more readable and separates business conditions from HTML.

Comment: This should help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2586842/is-ternary-operator-if-else-or-logical-or-faster-in-javascript/25344701#25344701

Comment: @DheerajKumar I had read this to, but still this is different from that or I'm mistaken?

Comment: @PrithiviRaj sadly this does not count for an reactive form input. It has it own validations. Next to that I just try to prevent to type dot and comma at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both ternary template expression and method call will have roughly same performance impact in AOT compilation mode, which is negligible here and isn't a subject for optimization.

```
$event.keyCode !== 188 ? $event.keyCode !== 190: $event.preventDefault()
```

and

```
if (_event.keyCode === 188 || _event.keyCode === 190)
{
    _event.preventDefault();
}
```

are different things.

Ternary expression won't call `$event.preventDefault()` in case when `$event.keyCode === 190`.

It should be:

```
($event.keyCode === 188 || $event.keyCode === 190) && $event.preventDefault()
```

And a cleaner way is to move implementation details to `keypress` method.

Another option is to use pure pipe, but it won't have any performance benefits in this case because `$event` is new object every time.

Comment: Cheers. Ternary won't call $event.preventDefault() if it's a number but if it's a comma or dot it will excute the else. I already use this in my application ;)