# How to optimize if statement given the if statement has: > or <

Tags: python, if-statement

How to make code similar to the one below run faster.

I know you can use a dictionary for equality if-statements but no sure with this one.

```
Delta = 3
if (x - y) >= Delta:
    pass
elif y < Delta:
    pass
else:
    pass
```

Comment: Why you think that can run faster?

Comment: Please supply a description of how you envision this running faster -- say in assembler language, or similar low-level instructions.  I don't see it.

Comment: what is `x` and `y`? if numbers, I would say "do not bother with it"

Comment: If the two clauses of `Do something else` are the *same* "something else", then your `elif` clause is a waste of time and space.

Comment: Most of all, what do you see controlling at this level of code, that the common optimization will not do for you?

Comment: Everyone, I think he's wondering if there's something analogous to dispatch tables, which can be used for code that's like switch/case. The simple answer is that there isn't anything similar when you're doing inequality comparisons.

Comment: Thank you, everyone, x and y are numbers, i just want to run the code faster, if this is possible, when the conditional statement in the if-statement has a > or <

Comment: @Prune - um, we need our examples to be in assembler now? I'm not sure what your problem with "do something else" is, should that have been "do something elser"? And what is the "common optimization" in this case? I think that's what OP is asking in the first place.

Comment: I don't see a way to optimize the data-control graph for this example, so I'm wondering what OP sees that I don't.  Optimization for code this simple (i.e. good example) might well be expressed in assembly.  No, it's not *required* -- just a straightforward way to express what faster result might be expected.

Comment: I think the answer is here in the link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2586842/is-ternary-operator-if-else-or-logical-or-faster-in-javascript

Comment: It's unlikely that the cost of computing `x - y >= Delta` and `y < Delta` when neither ends up being true is going to be the bottleneck of your program.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example of how a dictionary lookup would look here, if you really wanted to use one:

```
def do_something():
    pass

def do_something_else_1():
    pass

def do_something_else_2():
    pass

{
    y < Delta: do_something_else_1,
    x - y >= Delta: do_something
}.get(True, do_something_else_2)()
```

But I can guarantee you this will run slower (mainly because all the conditions are greedily evaluated now, instead of lazily). The reason you cannot optimize your existing code with a dictionary lookup is because a dictionary lookup excels where computing a hash followed by computing equality with the narrowed search space is faster than computing equality with the entire search space. Because of this benefit, you have to pay the upfront cost of constructing the hash table in the first place.

However, you aren't checking equality here. You're using the inequality functions `<` and `>=`, which don't play nice with the concept of a hash table. The hash of a `bool` (the result of this inequality function) is no quicker to compute compared to using the `bool` itself, which means that constructing the hash table here will outweigh any time savings you get by using the constructed hash table immediately afterwards. Seeing as `x` and `y` may change each time, there's no way for you to cache this hash table, meaning you suffer the cost of construction each time.

Keep the code as it is.

Answer (score 0):

Optimization usually takes advantage of some common expression or common code.  You have none here.  At the register level, your comparisons look like:

```
load r1, x
sub  r1, y
sub  r1, 3
brlt ELIF    # if less than 0, branch to ELIF
# TRUE-clause stuff, aka "Do something"
br ENDIF

ELIF:
load r1, y
sub  r1, 3
brge ELSE    # if >= 0, branch to ELSE
# ELIF-clause stuff, aka "Do something else #1"

ELSE:
# ELSE-caluse stuff, aka "Do something else #2"

ENDIF:
# Remainder of program
```

The only commonality her in either data or flow is loading `y` into a register.  Any reasonably aware optimization level will do this for you -- it will alter the first expression to load `y` into `r2`, a trivial cost in micro-instruction utilization.

There appears to be nothing else to optimize here.  The normal flow analysis will recognize that `3` is a constant within this block, and substitute the immediate operand for `Delta`.