# Improving render of a component: ? operator or if statement?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, performance, if-statement, rendering

I have a component with two "phases", depending on a condition.
Something like:

```
if(example){
  return <div> PHASE TWO </div>
} else {
  return <div> PHASE ONE </div>
}
```

I was wondering if it's better to create two const referring to the two phases or the previous approach in terms of performance.

```
const phaseOne = () => {
  <div> PHASE ONE </div>
}

const phaseTwo = () => {
  <div> PHASE TWO </div>
}

return example ? phaseTwo() : phaseOne();
```

In a first moment, I automatically used the second approach (ChatGPT approved), but my senior told me that was better the first one.
I know, the second one is better in readability, but I don't see the performance differences.

? operator or IF statement?

Comment: This is likely to be met with opiniated answers. I would argue that for performance, both are relatively equal. For readability (and this is likely where the opinions will come in), I would say the first one is more readable, and would prefer to write (and read) the first method. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2586842/15291770) already discusses the speed differences between if-else and ternary operator - the common theme is "negligible"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> the second one is better in readability

That's all.
it is not about `?` or `if` they are the same thing.
 in terms of performance, I will not say that the first is more performant because the difference is negligible, but in the second React have to create the two function on each render.